# How can you count and group the last 12 months in SQL?

Tags: sql

Example

`interviewed` table to query:

| id | interviewed_on_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-31 |
| 2 | 2021-01-25 |
| 3 | 2021-01-25 |
| 4 | 2021-02-13 |
| 5 | 2022-05-25 |
| 6 | 2022-05-26 |

Result I would like to obtain:

| date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12 | 1 |
| 2021-01 | 3 |
| 2021-02 | 4 |
| 2022-05 | 6 |

Thanks for you help!

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: Why should `2021-01` get 3, and `2022-05` get 6? Do you want to group the last 12 months? If yes I think you know that between 2020-12 and 2022-05 there's more than 12 months.

Comment: Hi, every months count depends on the previous one. 2021-01 has two dates of interview but in 2020-12 I have one, therefore 2021-01 get 3. Yes, there are more than 12 months so the result should include only 2022-05 (now() - INTERVAL 12 month = 2022-05). I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS you didn't specify your rdms, i used MySQL for my approach, as every rdms may have another syntax for this or even misses `WINDOW functions` all together.

Second in your description are you talking about **data from the last 12 months** , but you haven't any in your data, that is why i added on query without `WHERE'`clause, onyl to demonstrate that it works

The idea first select the count of all YEAR/months and then sue the cumultatove `SUM` function of the window function.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE interview (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `interviewed_on_date`date
> );
>
> INSERT INTO interview
>   (`id`, `interviewed_on_date`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '2020-12-31'),
>   ('2', '2021-01-25'),
>   ('3', '2021-01-25'),
>   ('4', '2021-02-13'),
>   ('5', '2022-05-25'),
>   ('6', '2022-05-26');
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (SELECT
>  DATE_FORMAT(interviewed_on_date, '%Y-%m') myyeamon,
>  COunt(*) count_
>  FROM interview
>  GROUP BY 1)
>  SELECT myyeamon,
>  sum(count_) OVER (ORDER BY  myyeamon) count_
>  FROM CTE
> ```
>
> ```
> myyeamon | count_
> :------- | -----:
> 2020-12  |      1
> 2021-01  |      3
> 2021-02  |      4
> 2022-05  |      6
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (SELECT
>  DATE_FORMAT(interviewed_on_date, '%Y-%m') myyeamon,
>  COunt(*) count_
>  FROM interview
>  WHERE `interviewed_on_date` BETWEEN curdate() - INTERVAL - 12 MONTH AND curdate()
>  GROUP BY 1)
>  SELECT myyeamon,
>  sum(count_) OVER (ORDER BY  myyeamon) count_
>  FROM CTE
> ```
>
> ```
> myyeamon | count_
> :------- | -----:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5d7edc32d2086ca3e5eb00aa887aa4f2)*

This is, when you only want the year 2022

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (SELECT
>  DATE_FORMAT(interviewed_on_date, '%Y-%m') myyeamon,
>  COunt(*) count_
>  FROM interview
>  WHERE YEAR(`interviewed_on_date`) = 2022
>  GROUP BY 1)
>  SELECT myyeamon,
>  sum(count_) OVER (ORDER BY  myyeamon) count_
>  FROM CTE
> ```
>
> ```
> myyeamon | count_
> :------- | -----:
> 2022-05  |      2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=300c12d510473df1012b0c68e965d062)*

To get the complete number but only the one entry you need `LIMIT`

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (SELECT
>  DATE_FORMAT(interviewed_on_date, '%Y-%m') myyeamon,
>  COunt(*) count_
>  FROM interview
>  GROUP BY 1)
>  SELECT myyeamon,
>  sum(count_) OVER (ORDER BY  myyeamon) count_
>  FROM CTE
>  ORDER BY myyeamon DESC
>  LIMIT 1
> ```
>
> ```
> myyeamon | count_
> :------- | -----:
> 2022-05  |      6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2eb3fd35e8bf6ca17f34597190661d14)*

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your solution! One last question: how would you select only 2022 dates?

Comment: i added another qiery at the end of my answer, that shiows how you do it

Comment: Hi! How can I obtain 6 for 2022? Sorry, I didn't explain myself very well, but this the problem I am having: I don't want to lose the counting when I select the values for each year. Thank you!

Comment: yes you can i added another query to demonstarte

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YEAR(interviewed_on_date), MONTH(interviewed_on_date), -- PK of result table.
    FORMAT(MAX(interviewed_on_date), 'yyyy-MM'), -- Label column.
    COUNT(*) -- Value column.
FROM interviewed
GROUP BY YEAR(interviewed_on_date), MONTH(interviewed_on_date)
```

`MAX` is an easy way to choose any old representative from each group of rows -- every row in each group has the same year and date.

Comment: Hi! This counts the months individually. My monthly count depends on the previous one. So if on 2022-12 I have one date, 2021-01 there are two dates, means that for 2021-01 the count should be 3. Thanks for your help!